# How can I set a device label for a devices in the Nautilus sidebar?

Tags: nautilus, mount

When I mount any device (Windows partition, external HDD, flash drive, TrueCrypt mounts...) they appear in my Nautilus sidebar as "75 GB volume", "11 GB volume", etc. How can I change their label to be more meaningful? (that is, to use the volume label and/or a label of my choosing)

Answer (score 1):

Issue following command to know the correct drive name:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

My USB is /dev/sdc1. If you're not sure, remove the USB and issue the command again and compare which /dev/sdc is missing.

To change the label use this with USBDisk being the name you want the drive to have:

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdc6 USBDisk
```

OR do it with the GUI:

Install gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open gparted and make sure the drive you want to label is unmounted, if it's mounted you can unmount it in Gparted, right click on the drive and select unmount.

To label a drive right click on the drive you want to label and select Label, enter the desired label.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtK25.png]

and click apply (the green V) and that's it

Answer (score 0):

goto Dash home and type Disks. once it is opened, you need to unmount a drive you wish to rename. then click on "more actions" icon.
now click on "Edit Filesystem Label" and you can rename a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Options :

- You can change devices labels from gparted.

You can edit labels with commands e2label and tune2fs :

- "sudo e2label /dev/DEVICE LABEL"
- "sudo tune2fs -L LABEL /dev/DEVICE"

You probably need to unmount your device before doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can use disk utility. Select device/Partition and rename Label. Your changes made in Renaming Partition Name in windows will also rename in Ubuntu.