# Broken shorcuts, Dropbox folder, etc due to mount address changing

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts, dropbox

I use Ubuntu 14.04. The partition where my files are located is not the same as the one my system is installed in. If I create a shortcut to a folder in the data partition and place that shortcut in my desktop, it works perfectly until I restart the system, then it breaks. It's happening all the time. I could live with that, but apparently Dropbox can't, or any other program using files from the data partition. Any ideas?

It looks like this:

```
/media/myname/8440508D405087B6/Dropbox
```

The numbers seem to change every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Assign a label](https://askubuntu.com/q/391987/300458) to this partition;
2. For auto-mounting, add it to `/etc/fstab` file (for example, look here: [How to automount NTFS partitions ?](https://askubuntu.com/q/46588/300458) or here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#ntfs).